# Facebook graph api not sending all data in android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get user_id, name & email from facebook via graph API. but its not sending me the email. I'm using a function like this:

```
void callGraphApi() {
        accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                accessToken,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {

                        tv_response.setText(response.toString());
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

I'm only getting a response like this:

```
{"id":"1480750682018443","name":"Ogwemuvwem Ossas","gender":"male"}, error: null}
```

Any solution??

Comment: Are you sure you have e-mail address in extended permissions?

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your facebook developer dashboard Go to **App review** in There you can see your data request permission.

[image]

If email permission not listed there you have to add it by click **start a submission** button on the same page.

[image]

From facebook Docs:

> Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed
>   you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for
>   Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email
>   field may be empty.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this new api. You can pass permissions in ArrayList like this.

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        getUserDetails(loginResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // App code
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        // App code
    }
});
```

You can handle LoginResult like this.

```
  // Get Facebook login results
    protected void getUserDetails(LoginResult loginResult) {
        GraphRequest data_request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject json_object, GraphResponse response) {

                        Log.i("onfbCompleted: ", json_object.toString());                    

                    }

                });
        Bundle permission_param = new Bundle();
        permission_param.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.width(120).height(120)");
        data_request.setParameters(permission_param);
        data_request.executeAsync();

    }
```

I Hope it's help for you. :)

Comment: You need to call ' CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();' fb sdk in Oncreate